# Is $BG =EG / G$ a CW complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-actions, cw-complexes

am currently working through J.Rosenbergs construction of classifying Spaces for the +-construction of higher K-Theory. He defines a CW-complex EG as the direct limit of the inductively defined Spaces
$$ X_n = X_{n-1} \ast G$$
where $X_0 = G$ with the discrete topology and $\ast$ is the join of topological spaces. My questions are:

1. How do I show that $X_n$ is a CW-complex for every $n$? I know the cell-decomposition: every $X_n^j$ arises from $X^{j-1}_n$ by attaching the following cells:

   - for $j>0$ the $j$-cells of $X_{n-1}$ and the $j-1$-cells of $X_{n-1}$ joint with $g \in G$ or
   - for $j = 0$ the $0$-cells of $X_{n-1}$ disjoint with a copy of $G$.

   but how do I show the Pushout, that formally shows that every $X_n^j$ arises from $X_n^{j-1}$ by attaching $j$-cells?
2. The obvious $G$-operation on $EG$ is free and properly discontinuous. I want to show that $BG=EG/G$ is also a CW-complex, so I want to show that it even is a $G$-CW-complex. Do I know for $G$-CW-complexes $X$, that $X/G$ is again a CW-complex?

I would be grateful for every help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ,If you have $G$- CW complex then $X/G$ is a genuine CW - complex.Because let $X$ and $Y$ be two $G$ -spaces and $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a $G$-map and $C_f$ be cofibre of it. Then $C_f/G$ is the cofibre of $X/G \rightarrow Y/G$.

Comment: Thank you, but how do I know from the cofiber of a map, that the quotient of my CW-complex is also a CW-complex? I know that for $m \leq n$: $X_m \rightarrow X_n$ is a cofibration, but I think for your argument I need to have a map $f$ sth. $C_f$ is my CW-complex?

Comment: Use definition of G -CW- complex.i.e.$\coprod G \times_H S^n \rightarrow X^{(n)} \rightarrow X^{(n+1)}$ is a $G$ - cofibre sequeunce.